# How can I get rid of fat breast

Tags: weight-loss

I am computer science student. To do programming homework, I have left fat stomach and breast.

In order to get rid of fat stomach, I have started to do sit-ups. However, How can I get rid of fat breast.

NOTE: I am male.

Comment: Targeting fat loss from areas can't be done. See this other question that's similar to yours: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/718/how-to-lose-manboobs

Answer (score 3):

The breast is adipose tissue, or fat.  It's common in teenage males, those who take anabolic steroids, and older men.  You do need to attack it on two fronts:

- Get leaner.  You may have a flat stomach, but you still have some extra fat.  This is done with your diet.
- Get stronger.  This will help you burn more calories over the long run, and build the muscle that is underneath the adipose tissue.

You will be amazed at what you can do with just body weight exercise.  Try this challenge for 60 days:

- Only let yourself have junk food for one 3 hour block during a calendar week.  Make sure you have a serving of protein with every meal (best is animal protein like beef or chicken).  Junk food is anything fried, found in the snack aisle, or classified as a dessert (this includes donuts).
- Start with 10 pushups, 10 situps, 10 lunges
- Each day add one more of each.  You can split the work up into multiple sets if you need to.

See what happens after 60 days.  This is not a fully balanced workout, as you aren't doing much for your back.  However, it's a start.  Feel free to do other exercises during the day if you want, but this is your baseline activity.  Don't jump ahead, build up one rep a day.

Comment: I just want to echo Berin's comment regarding diet. it is very, very easy for men to focus on the exercise portion of the equation but I firmly believe, as a person who was once over 310 pounds and obese, that diet is more important than training. That does not mean you can train poorly or inconsistently, it just means that getting your diet right will bring you better results than just working out.

Comment: @Berin, good answer for enlarged breasts from fatty tissue, which appears to be the cause in gcc's question.  However, I would like to add a link to a [good article](http://www.medicinenet.com/gynecomastia/article.htm) that includes true gynecomastia (enlargement of glandular tissue located around the nipple) that can result from hormonal imbalances, medications or medical conditions.